# Backbone: refresh datatable after collection is changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

After a lot of googling I didn't find the answer. So,

**Question**

***What is a CORRECT way in Backbone.js to refresh my tables after collection is changed?***

By correct I mean I needn't to rewrite the whole table after adding single element to collection.

Comment: You should edit in your render() code for review

Comment: do you mean call render() function each time I add/remove one row? But in such case Backbone will recreate the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick the model index from the collection, and make sure your table's add row function insert elements at right index inside table tag.

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand I should write a function that calculate new_element_index and insert the element to the table. Maybe more simple way?

Comment: @nickole-abs you can get index of model by, collection.indexOf(model).